# Looping Two Values from a JSON Dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I know this should be simple, but in the dozens of questions I've read, there is no answer for this. I'm did a lot of reading about comprehensions [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions), but it's going a bit over my head on this.

I am trying to create a list of names and IDs from a Twitter API response. Right now, it only gives me the name and ID for the first result in the dictionary. I want a loop that gives me a list of all names and IDs.

You can see an example of the JSON response [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-ownerships) at the Twitter API docs.

My code:

```
twitterlists = twitter.show_owned_lists()
print("List name: "+json.dumps(twitterlists['lists'][0]['name'], skipkeys = True))
print("List ID: "+json.dumps(twitterlists['lists'][0]['id'], skipkeys = True))
```

Current response:

```
List name: "listname"
List ID: 12345
```

Desired response:

```
1. List name: listname. List ID: 123.
2. List name: listname2. List ID: 124.
3. List name: listname3. List ID: 125.
```

I also believe I can combine the two lines getting 'name' and 'id' into one, but I got an error along the way and was able to get part way there with the two lines. Happy to be more efficient if you have any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `json.dumps()` to print a single value?

Comment: The only way I know how. I'm still pretty new to Python. I was following examples on getting values out of JSON responses.

Comment: Normally you use `str()` to convert a value to a string. But `name` is already a string, you don't need to convert it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a list with `[0]` just gives you the first element.  You want to iterate over the list:

```
twitterlists = twitter.show_owned_lists()['lists']
for i in twitterlists:
    print(f"List name: {i['name']}.  List ID: {i['id']}.")
```

Comment: Use `enumerate()` so you can also print the numbers at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried adding enumerate a few different ways and none have worked. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks for the suggestions so far!

Comment: @Eric `for num, i in enumerate(twitterlists, 1):`